# Quoting of SQL excuted via psql via ssh

Tags: shell, quoting

I want to execute this SQL line:

```
select * from "foo" where name='bar'
```

I call above line "sql_line" in the next statements.

Now I want to call this via `psql`:

```
psql -c sql_line
```

Now I want to call this via `ssh`:

```
ssh remote-host psql -c sql_line
```

How to quote this, to get it right?

I tried this, but this fails:

```
ssh remote-host psql -c "select * from \"foo\" where name='bar'"
```

I am using GNU bash, Version 4.3.48

Comment: Why do we need to do with `ssh` in particular? cant we configure remote acces in psql?

Comment: @SivaPrasath this does not work. The bash thinks the statement is not finished yet. It displays `>` after I am hitting enter.

Comment: @SivaPrasath ssh is needed. A firewall is blocking direct connections to the DB.

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127483/not-executing-postgresql-query-on-remote-machine-with-ssh